# Does mean of residuals become zero in least-squares fitting of nonlinear regression model?

Tags: regression, least-squares, residuals, nonlinear-regression

It is well known that the (sample) mean of residuals becomes zero in an unweighted OLS fitting of a linear regression model. How about the case for the nonlinear model?

I have numerically tested whether the mean of residuals become zero in least-squares fitting of the following models for example.

y = b1 / (x + b2) + error

y = b1 * exp(b2 * x) + error

I had expected that for such nonlinear models without intercept to be estimated, the mean of residuals (predicted y - observed y) would not be generally zero. However, according to my numerical tests, where I generated the error term by using independent & zero-mean Gaussian pseudo-random numbers, the mean of residuals did not significantly deviated from zero.

Could anyone tell me whether the mean of residuals generally equals zero in unweighted least-squares fitting of nonlinear regression models?

**EDIT 230728 18:40JST**

I'm sorry some important conditions were missing.
I'm interested in a case where y is a continuous variable and has an independent zero-mean observation error (i.e., noise) following a Gaussian distribution.
In other words, the observation of y is generated by adding the true predictor of the model (with true coefficients) with an i.i.d. Gaussian error.
For example, if the true model is y = 1 / (x + 2) + error where error follows standard normal distribution, the observations of y should be generated by

```
    y <- 1 / (x + 2) + rnorm(N, mean = 0, sd = 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

**NO**

First, note that what you wrote only applies when there is an intercept. If your linear model lacks an intercept, then the mean of the residuals is not guaranteed to be zero.

For an example of a nonlinear model that uses the minimization of the sum of squares residuals to estimate the regression coefficients, consider the model below.

$$
\hat y_i = e^{
\hat\beta x_i
} \iff \log(\hat y_i)=\hat\beta x_i
$$

I can fit this to some simulated data in software, using least squares as the function to minimize to calculate the estimated $\hat\beta$.

```r
set.seed(2023)
N <- 100
x <- rnorm(N)
y <- rbinom(N, 5, 0.5) + 1
L <- glm(y ~ 0 + x, family = gaussian(link = "log"))
mean(resid(L)) # About 2
```

I get a mean of the residuals of about $2$.

The `family = Gaussian` is what tells the software to minimize the sum of squared residuals, and `link = “log”` introduces nonlinearity.

**EDIT**

Even better than the comment might be an example with a totally continuous `y` with a $U(5, 6)$ distribution (both conditional and marginal distribution).

```r
set.seed(2023)
N <- 100
x <- rnorm(N)
y <- runif(N, 5, 6)
L <- glm(y ~ 0 + x, family = gaussian(link = "log"))
mean(resid(L))   # About 4
t.test(resid(L)) # p < 2.2e-16, strong evidence against a mean of zero
```

**EDIT 2**

> I'm interested in a case where y is a continuous variable and has an independent zero-mean observation error (i.e., noise) following a Gaussian distribution. In other words, the observation of y is generated by adding the true predictor of the model (with true coefficients) with an i.i.d. Gaussian error.

The examples below seems to satisfy your criteria, and the means of the residuals are not zero.

```r
set.seed(2023)
N <- 100
x <- runif(N, 1000, 2000)
y <- log(x) + rnorm(N)
L <- glm(y ~ 0 + x, family = gaussian(link = "log"))
mean(resid(L))   # I get about 1
t.test(resid(L)) # p < 0.0001
```

```r
set.seed(2023)
N <- 100
x <- runif(N, 0, 0.01)
y <- y <- 100 / (x + 2) + rnorm(N, mean = 0, sd = 0.001) # Based on the given example
L <- glm(y ~ 0 + x, family = gaussian(link = "log"))
mean(resid(L))   # I get about 29
t.test(resid(L)) # p < 2.2e-16, strong evidence against a mean of zero
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed and helpful answer. I have run your GLM example script and confirmed that the mean of the residuals is not zero indeed. On the other hand, I am still not successful in making a case where y is a continuous variable and its observations are generated by y <- truey + rnorm(N, 0, sigma).

Comment: Let me report an example non-successful case of mine.

n.data <- 100
X <- runif(n = n.data, min = -3, max = 3)
Y.true <- exp(0.65 * X)
Y.obs <- Y.true + rnorm(n = n.data, mean = 0, sd = 1)

I generated X and Y.obs in this way and then fitted the predictor exp(coeff * X) to minimize RMS residuals (optimizing coeff), then calculated the mean of residuals (MR). After 1000 such trials, i got the following statistics for MR.

mean of MR: 0.00268.
standard error (S.D/sqrt(1000)) of MR: 0.00268.

Obviously, I cannot say the residuals are biased from this example.

Comment: @GreatJourney I do not follow what you’re doing or how it relates to what I’ve written about residual means in nonlinear models. Could you please clarify?

Comment: I am sorry. I'd like to get a theoretical or numerical proof that the mean of residuals does not always become zero in least-squares fitting of nonlinear regression models. Your first answer indeed gave me the numerical proof. However, the nonlinear models in my mind were those with continuous objective variables (y) (I am sorry that I didn't explicitly mention it in my question). That's why, I'd like to get another example where y is continuous and the mean of residuals (MR) significantly deviates from zero.

Comment: But so far I am not successful in creating such an example by myself. In the examples I have created so far, the mean of MR in multiple trials (with new X and Y generation in each trial) does not exceed two times of the standard error of MR, and hence I cannot say that MR is significantly deviated from zero. Is my intention clear enough?

Comment: @GreatJourney I just made an edit with such an example.

Comment: Thank you for giving another example. I'm afraid I have noticed that my specification was still not enough. I have edited my original question (added specifications after the original text). I'm sorry.

Comment: @GreatJourney I have provided another simulation that seems to satisfy your requirements. In the future, if you come up with a new question after the question you asked has been answered, please post a new question.

Comment: Thank you very much. OK, I have noted the posting rule. I'm also grateful for the two  new examples. I'm afraid they might not be satisfying my criteria "the observation of y is generated by adding the true predictor of the model (with true coefficients) with an i.i.d. Gaussian error."  For your first example, y is generated by "y = log(x) + error" while the model fitted is log(E(y)) = beta*x. Therefore, the y generation model seems to be different from the fitted model. I am sorry for bothering you many times. Should I post a new question now?